# Hibernate и целесообразность маппинга таблицы на java класс

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть таблица в БД - примерно 15 полей. И есть запрос в котором надо посчитать количество единиц в одном из этих полей. Можно сделать все через запрос sql, при помощи createSQLQuery например. Но хочу сделать это "фишкой" хибера. Для того чтобы воспользоваться фишкой, насколько я помню надо обязательно промаппить таблицу в классе. Но напрягает то что из-за одного запроса надо будет возиться с 15 полями. Обязательно ли мапить все поля? Просто мне кажется это неправильным действием... Можно ли воспользоваться для подсчета единиц(запрос в sql віглядел бі так: select count(*) from ...) какой-то фишкой хибера без маппинга/полного маппинга? Ну и соответсвенно вопрос чем бы воспользоваться?)

Comment: если вам нужно всего навсего кол-во то воспользуйтесь SQL, зачем вам маппить? Но если же все таки вы хотите маппить то можете замаппить одно поле, например, ID

Comment: @JVic а это нормальная практика? просто я как-бы всегда все поля маппил и связи описывал...

Comment: @АлександрПлющев не, не очень нормальная. Обычно разработчик или использует Hibernate или не использует.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev сто пудов! это из опыта, или сам догадался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate допускает маппинг не всех полей таблицы в поля класса, то есть вы можете иметь в таблице 15 полей, но замаппить скажем только 1 или 2 поля.

Только надо при этом помнить, что при операции вставки, если незамапленные поля таблицы будут требовать `not null` - будет выкинуто исключение.

Ну и естественно вы не сможете валидировать схему таблицы (поскольку схема таблицы будет отличаться от маппинга `Entity`)

В остальном, все будет работать - включая подсчет количества строк.